# how to access client desktop and to control mouse using tcp/ip protocol from server machine

Tags: sockets, tcp, remote-access, remote-desktop

I'm working on project to develop an software using the TCP/IP protocol. The basic function of the software is to access the client activity running on client machine from server machine, for example information about current running applications.

Also, I want to access desktop screen and mouse from client machine to server machine using TCP/IP protocol. What are the basic steps that I can follow to access the desktop and could handle client mouse from server machine using TCP/IP.

Comment: Too broad a question. Depending on the platform you'd use the provided APIs to access the data you want to relay back. Pick something simple and implement, like getting the system time. And move on from there adding things bit by bit.

Comment: i am using linux distribution.i am new to networking,as far as theory is concern i know some thing but i haven't implemented it practically.

Comment: You've got a long long long journey ahead of you, then. Start here: http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html and once you're able to connect one machine to another and relay simple messages, start developing more logic on top.

Comment: I'm already studying beej's guide to networking programming which is suggested by someone on this site, and i know how to connect two system using getaddrinfo(), socket(),listen(), bind(), send() and receive() function. but i have problem like how to get system date and time, login time and shutdown time. please suggest me.

Comment: Use the search please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to build a [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) or [RDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol) -like program.  There have been an explosion of these services/programs in the time since you asked the question, though I don't know how many might be open source.  I would start by investigating an Open Source VNC client and then see about adding an encrypted tunnel to keep the connection secure.

[UltraVNC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ultravnc/) and [TightVNC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vnc-tight/) are popular Open Source VNC clients.