# How to remove an array element in json-c?

Tags: arrays, json

Assuming the following JSON object, an array of [epoch, value] arrays:

```
[ [0,1], [1912312314,2], [1912312857,5] ]
```

What's the correct way to remove an element of the array ? The idea is to remove the one with an epoch alder than a given value. I use json-c 0.11.

I tried :

```
   json_object *jsonHeatmapObj;
   jsonHeatmapObj = json_tokener_parse ( "[ [0,1], [1912312314,2], [1912312857,5] ]" );

    for ( int idx=0 ; idx < json_object_array_length(jsonHeatmapObj) ; idx++ ) {
       json_object *curJsonHeatpointObj = json_object_array_get_idx ( jsonHeatmapObj , idx );
       int x = json_object_get_int ( json_object_array_get_idx ( curJsonHeatpointObj , 0 ) );
       if ( x < time(NULL) - 10 ) {
          json_object_put ( curJsonHeatpointObj );
       }
       printf("\t[%d]=%s\n", idx, json_object_to_json_string(jsonHeatmapObj));
    }
```

This fails (SIGSEGV) when calling json_object_to_json_string() with the adjusted object.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please include how did you read the `jsonHeatmapObj` variable from the provided JSON?

Comment: Updated the question : added call to json_tokener_parse().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two separate issues with that code: one is that it is using `json_object_put` as if `json_object_array_get_idx` had removed the element it returns from the original array (something that is not at all clear from the [API documentation](https://json-c.github.io/json-c/json-c-0.10/doc/html/json__object_8h.html#a5c9120a6d644ea12a61e2ec8520130c6)), and second that it uses `time(NULL)` as if it was returning an integer, but it is returning a `time_t` struct.

The first one can be solved by creating a new JSON array and only including items in it if the condition is met.  Here I am avoiding the second issue by using a time that is set to the largest value in the array:

```
struct json_object *newHeatMap = json_object_new_array();
for ( int idx=0 ; idx < json_object_array_length(jsonHeatmapObj) ; idx++ ) {
    json_object *curJsonHeatpointObj = json_object_array_get_idx ( jsonHeatmapObj , idx );
    int x = json_object_get_int ( json_object_array_get_idx ( curJsonHeatpointObj , 0 ) );
    if ( x < 1912312857 ) {
        json_object_array_add(newHeatMap, curJsonHeatpointObj);
    }
    printf("\t[%d]=%s\n", idx, json_object_to_json_string(newHeatMap));
}
```

I get the following results, which I hope are what you intend to see:

```
$ gcc -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib/ -ljson-c main.c && ./a.out example.json
    [0]=[ [ 0, 1 ] ]
    [1]=[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1912312314, 2 ] ]
    [2]=[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 1912312314, 2 ] ]
```

The second problem has already been answered for instance [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c)

Comment: Although this lookes more like a workaround, I'll accept this since I guess there is no better way to do it. I used json_object_array_add() instead of json_object_array_put_idx() to populate newHeatMap though.

Comment: @SCO: I have edited the post to use the function you mention.  Both give the same output.  Using `json_object_array_put_idx` would have kept the logic right even if you changed the index loop, but maybe `json_object_array_add` is more intuitive.  Otherwise: why does this look like a workaround?  Returning a new object instead of mutating one is not a bad pattern, specially if threading is involved.

Comment: From what I remember, the json_object_array_put_idx() segfaulted. I came to the conclusion that json_object_array_put_idx() used idx which was out-of-bounds for newHeatMap. For example, json_object_array_put_idx()'ing curJsonHeatpointObj at index 2 of newHeatMap where neither objects at indexes 0 or 1 were added previously (making newHeatMap array 0-sized) would make it SIGSEGV. I always expect libraries to allow for inplace replacement (you are right regarding MT, in that case, I just mutex' the change when it is acceptable to do so) because the code is more readable, IMHO :). Thank you !

Comment: @SCO : you are right about segfaulting if an intermediate element is skipped. I did not take that into account, and now the answer is better.  Take care with mutating state, it is the source of all evil :)

Comment: "Take care with mutating state", will remember this ! :)