# Is any way for Retrieving current date and time without using [NSDate date]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I make a application in which i need to show a 30 min countdown timer,after 30 min i need to show that coupons is expired.It work fine.

```
{    
NSInteger seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateDue];
}
```

But if somebody change the mobile date or time, the timer is disturb and it show wrong values.So is this any way to find current date and time without using **[NSDate date]** so i use it for my countdown timer.Please give your suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `CACurrentMediaTime()`. Or `mach_absolute_time()`.

Comment: CACurrentMediaTime() is not a timer. It's a wrapper around the most accurate time function in the system: mach_absolute_time(). So if you really care what time it is right now, and you'd like that in a human-understandable number, CACurrentMediaTime() is your function. mach_absolute_time() will give you a really accurate number, but it's based on the Mach absolute time unit which doesn't actually map to anything pesky humans think in (and every CPU has a different scale). That's why we have CACurrentMediaTime() to make our lives easier.

Answer (score 0):

Objective c is just c at its heart; you can use any standard ansi-c compliant methods such as:

```
time_t time;
struct tm * timeinfo; 
time (&time);
timeinfo = localtime (&time);
```

Now that you have a local representation of the time, you can get at particulars such as:

```
Year:  "timeinfo->tm_year+1900;"
Month: "timeinfo->tm_mon+1;"
Date:  "timeinfo->tm_mday;"
Hour:  "timeinfo->tm_hour;"
Mins:  "timeinfo->tm_min;"
Secs:  "timeinfo->tm_sec;"
```

This time is local; to get GMT time, replace the call to localtime() with gmtime().

Sourced gratefully from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31646117/2748303

Happy Hacking!

Edit:  It seems like what you really want is an absolute epoc timestamp for when the counter starts, and one for when it finishes.

In that case, I would use:

```
time_t now = time(0);
```

to return the milliseconds since epoc, and do your comparisons appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your time but my problem is that i need a datetime which is not affected even the mobile user change the time or date from setting, so i can run my count down based on that datetime.I use to dates for countdown timer one is when it is started and other one is current and i take difference time between two dates and show that timer