# process creation time in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocess

I am making c source file. And I have a question.

Is there a struct that manages process(or thread) creation time?

In this context, creation time is

> ***FROM*** just before creation function is called ***UNTIL*** child process(or thread) executes first line

thank you.

Comment: Can you just take the time when the process starts, ex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c

Comment: You can use the Linux command `ps -p YOUR_PID -o lstart` to get the created time.

Comment: thanks, however,
I am just wondering whether a STRUCT (is updated by kernel) managing process creation time exists or not.

Comment: This may be helpful, take a look:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h