# print date on same line as other variables in printf

Tags: c, printf, system

I am trying to use `system("date")` in `printf` but I would like it on the same line and I do not know how to format it properly. Any suggestions.

```
printf("Temperature %.2f date %d \n", val, system("date"));
```

Comment: [`system()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) does not do what you appear to want it to do.

Comment: perhaps you can use  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Comment: Or : [Get the current time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

The `system` function returns the exit status of the given external command, which if successful will typically be 0.  The specific command being run is outside of your process so you don't have too much control over what it outputs.

Rather than call an external command, there are functions you can call to get the information you want.

You need to first use the `time` function, which gives you the time in seconds since the UNIX epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.  Then pass this to the `ctime` function which gives you a text representation of the time:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
printf("date is %s", ctime(&t));
```

Comment: Isn't it that `ctime()` suffixes its result with a new-line? ;-)

Comment: @alk It sure does.  And if you fix it by using `%.24s` (as is quite common), you've just introduced the dread y10k bug.

Comment: @SteveSummit `y10k bug` I wouldn't care. :)