# How to store the current date in a struct?

Tags: c, struct, current-time

```
struct date{
  int date;
  int month;
  int year
};

struct date current_date;
```

I have this struct. Then I wanna store the current date in current_date. How can I do this using C language?

Thank You so much!

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c). `localtime` will help you get what you want

Comment: Your question is - how to get current date. Storing is obvious: `current_date.date = <date_source>; current_date.month = <date_source>; current_date.year = <date_source>;`

Comment: @i486 Yeah. What should I use for <date_source> That's my qestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the current time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c)

Comment: Under Windows call `GetSystemTime()` or `GetLocalTime()` to get current date in `SYSTEMTIME` structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[struct tm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm) is a very standard structure for representing a broken down time representation with second resolution.

You would:

```
// get current time
time_t t = time(NULL);
struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
// assign to your structure
current_date.date = tm->tm_mday;
current_date.month = tm->tm_mon + 1;
current_date.year = tm->tm_mon + 1900;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello in this source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/getdate-and-setdate-function-in-c-with-examples/

It says that getdate() function might be useful to you. It works like this:

```
 struct date yourdate; 
 getdate(&yourdate);  
 current_date.day = yourdate.da_day
```

And you should import   `#include <dos.h>`

Comment: Huh? `dos.h`? I've checked [C11 Standard - 7.1.2 Standard headers(p2)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2) and nowhere is `dos.h` listed. Where does that header come from?