# Measuring real time, system time, and user time in C

Tags: c, time

I have been told `time` command can calculate real time, user time, and system time. But according to the internet `time` returns time passed since January 1st 1970. Maybe i need to pass some special parameter to calculate details of execution time?

Edit

I suppose this is the answer for my question: [Execution time of C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248915/execution-time-of-c-program)

I consider the question closed.

Comment: Probably they were talking about `times` not `time`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the current time in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141960/get-the-current-time-in-c)

Comment: No, [the `time()` function in the C11 Standard Library](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.4) "determines the current calendar time (in an unspecified encoding)"; no mention of user time or system time or processor time.

Answer (score 0):

use the function: `clock_gettime()` see [man clock_gettime](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) for the details of how to use this function.